# How to edit "required" attribute, and set it from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, requiredfieldvalidator

is there some way to edit the messages shown when a require input field is not filled?

Can I check if a specific field content is valid (according to some rules) and eventually add the required attribute and activate it? Otherwise, is there some CSS rules to make the border red and show the messagebox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using jQuery validator ?

Comment: How do you make the validation? using validation plugin? using required in html5?

Comment: google 'jquery validation'. it may help you.

Comment: I would avoid to use jquery validation plugin, because I only need to check content from a single input field. But, if there is not a solution, I'll use this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume u r using jquery validation plugin...
To change required message for all use below..

```
$.validator.messages.required = 'required';
```

to change for particular element use below...

```
$("#EnquiryText").rules("remove"); 
$("#EnquiryText").rules("add", { 
    required: true, 
    messages: { 
        required: <your message>
    } 
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for an easier solution, because I only need to do that on a single input field. It's easier for me, to check the content and set the error to that field, than including the form validation plugin.
That's all, but if there are no other solution, I will use this.

Comment: When i tried the message isn't displayed. Where i'm wrong? I gave as string

Answer (score 0):

You mean the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute?

```
$("#theinput").attr("placeholder", "Some Text")
```

Note that that feature of HTML5 doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

when you dont want to use a plugin, you can add a label(on the fly) position absolute... or just add a border
jQuery:

```
  $("#yourInput").addClass("borderValidate")
```

css:

```
.borderValidate{
border: 2px solid red;
}
```